# What are the Arabic Superscript Number?

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to know what is the Unicode of the superscript of the ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT (from 1 to 9). superscript of Number 1 is 185, superscript of Arabic-Indic 1?

Comment: See unicode.org for a list of the code points for the information you are asking.

Comment: Does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

Answer (score 0):

As I am aware, there are no specific Unicodes for ARABIC-INDIC DIGITS Superscript, i.e. the digits <sup>٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩</sup>

One solution for display purposes is HTML using the HTML "sup" Tag; as I just did in the above numbers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>أرقام<sup>٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩</sup>أرقام</p>
<p>الرقم هو<sup>٣</sup>٩٩</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am looking for a unicode of ARABIC-INDIC DIGITS Superscript to use as function in Excel.

Comment: @Mohamed In MSOffice Applications (Word and Excel) you can use Superscript very easily by using the font change

Comment: I know I can use Superscript by highlighting the number. I am looking for unicode to use in a formula if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In MSOffice Applications (Word and Excel) you can use Superscript very easily by using the font change. Here is an example in Excel

You can also use the `Font.Superscript = True` from VBA.

[image].